# How to update the intent of an existing activity while calling startActivity?

Tags: android

I am having two activities, say activity A and B. Activity A is an ListActivity, and when the items in the list is selected, it will call startActivity() to bring up B. The problem here is that when I am in B and click the home key, and then go to the application launcher to resume my application, A will be brought up again. This time when I click a different item in A, it will bring up B with the old data of the previously selected item before the home key was clicked.

After examinzing the code, I found that the startActivity does not update the intent of B. I found a post here about the similar question, and the answer was to overwrite the onNewIntent. However, I found that it doesn't work, because this method never get called when the second time I call startActivity. I am sure that this is the same instance, because I've printed out the instance number. Is there any other ways to update the intent of the activity? Or I need some other settings to make the onNewIntent get called? I didn't set any flags or launch modes, so everything is default.

Comment: When do you update the UI data from the intent? `onCreate` or `onStart`??

Comment: Please post your code from onItemClick

Comment: I update my UI in onStart. I am writing code for my company, so the detail can't be posted here. but I can give some similar codes

Comment: protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id)
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
      intent.putExtra(B.EXTRA, something);
      startActivity(intent);
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) { 
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class); 
   intent.putExtra(B.EXTRA, something); 
   startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Comment: I understand why. My intent does not specify any data, type, action, or category. Android will consider that as a same intent with the old one, so the onNewIntent is not called.